# Chrome shows password instead email on autofill

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, autocomplete, semantic-ui, react-router-dom

We have SPA using react. At first render of the views everything works fine. Strange things happen when I navigate through different account views, for example, If I switch back end forth to **signin** and **reset password** multiple times, When I click to input, browser puts password instead email.

[image]

We are using react-semantic-ui forms and inputs. But I believe they don't modify autofilling

This is rendered input field

```
<input name="email" autocomplete="email" maxlength="250">
```

We don't want to set `autocomplete="off"`

I tried to give new key to the component to force remounting each time but with no success.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you fixed it?

Comment: @Georgy No I couldn't, seems like bug. It drove me crazy.

Comment: I have the same issue with Angular application. I have a login form inside a popup dialog. All the autocomplete attributes are set correctly and everything was working ok until 2 or 3 months ago. Now when I open the login dialog and try auto-filling the username, it shows the password. If I close the dialog and open it again, it works correctly. No solution found yet, I am starting to think it is a Chrome bug :/

Comment: @FilipVoska Yep mate, we gave up finding solution and considered as a Chrome bug.

Comment: The issue stopped happening to me, I didn't change anything, so my guess is that it is now resolved in Chrome if my theory that it was a Chrome bug was correct. I am on 79.0.3945.130